# Are all types declared with newtype phantom types

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming

I am learning about phantom types in Haskell. I know that phantom types are parameterised types whose parameters do not appear on the right hand side of its definition.
However, I would like to know whether all types declared with `newtype` are phantom types.

When I try to compile a program with the following code:

```
newtype SpecialInt Int = Special Int
```

I get an error stating:

```
 Unexpected type ‘Int’
    In the newtype declaration for ‘SpecialInt’
    A newtype declaration should have form
      newtype SpecialInt a = ...
```

Which leads me to believe that newtypes are phantom types if the type parameter on the left hand side doesn't appear on the right hand side.
E.g.

```
newtype SpecialInt a = Special a
```

Would not be a phantom type, but

```
newtype SpecialInt a = Special Int
```

would be a phantom type.
Therefore not all types declared with `newtype` are phantom types. However, I am not sure if my reasoning is correct.

Comment: You could write `newtype SpecialInt = Special Int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Which leads me to believe that newtypes are phantom types if the type parameter on the left hand side doesn't appear on the right hand side. E.g.

Well this is a consequence of your quoted definitions. You say that:

> I know that phantom types are parameterised types whose parameters do not appear on the right hand side of its definition.

Since `newtype` is a way to define a type, and since for parameterized types with parameters that do not appear at the right side are phantom types, types originating from a `newtype` clause with a type parameter that do not appear at the right side are phantom types as well.

> I would like to know whether all types declared with newtype are phantom types.

**No**, since for example a `newtype` without any type parameter, or a `newtype` with type parameters where are type parameters are used at the right side are *not* phantom types.

> When I try to compile a program with the following code:
>
> ```
> newtype SpecialInt Int = Special Int
> ```
>
> I get an error (..)

Type variables at the left side are, well, *variables*. `Int` is not a variable (it starts with an uppercase), so the above does not make much sense. If you want to define a `SpecialInt`, you should define this as:

```
newtype SpecialInt = Special Int
```

so without an `Int` at the left side of the `=` token.